# Treating a quote block similarly to a figure in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

Been trying to figure out how to achieve this but can only find ways to do it within the figure environment using `wrapfig`. I'm using the `epigraph` package to generate the quote style (as in the screenshot). The current behavior is in this screenshot [image: Current behavior] and generated by the code

```
\subsection{Methods}

\lipsum[1-2]

\epigraph{Models, of course, are never true, but fortunately it is only necessary that they be useful.}{\textcite{Box1979-em}}
```

However, the below image is how I wish it to look, but unsure how to achieve this?

[image: Desired behavior]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a MWE, I had to make some adjustments; but this appears to work.

[image: Epigraph in wrapfigure]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\subsection{Methods}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.43\linewidth} % manual adjustment required
    \epigraph{Models, of course, are never true, but fortunately it is only necessary that they be useful.}{Box (1979)}
  \end{minipage}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```